# Get DAG from airflow

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to render the DAG as a tree for documentation, is there a direct way to get this ?

Right now I'm manually generating DOT files with (partial code):

```
for task in dag.tasks:
    print("\t%s;" % task.task_id)
    relatives = [r.task_id for r in task.get_direct_relatives()]
    for r in relatives:
        print("\t%s -- %s;" % (task.task_id, r))
```

Which works, but I need to dynamically import all DAGs externally..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `airflow.models.DagBag` object to enumerate the `DAG` objects.

```
from airflow.models import DagBag

for dag in DagBag().dags.values():
  for task in dag.tasks:
    [...]
```

Comment: Using DagBag prints a lot of unwanted things in the log. Is there a way to suppress that?